# Is the execution of statements in the following code changed by compiler optimization?

Tags: java, compiler-optimization, causality, internal-compiler-error

In a [recent related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67949556/10115137) question I found that the following code

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
/*1*/        int x;
/*2*/        boolean found = false;
/*3*/        if (!found)
/*4*/            x = -1;

/*5*/        System.out.println(x);
    }
```

has the compiler error that x isn't init.(initialized). I am amazed that the compiler isn't able to reason the init. especially since this code doesn't seem to require any runtime reasoning as follows:

1. At the indicated line 2, `found` is set `false`.
2. There is no code between lines 2 and 3.
3. So arriving at line 3, `!found` is necessarily `true` so init is inevitable.

I wonder if this is correct. I vaguely remember that compiler optimization can change the order in which statements are executed. Does that play a role here? Is it possible that line 5 is being reached before lines 3 and 4?

---

**Env.**
openjdk 15.0.2 2021-01-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 15.0.2+7-27)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 15.0.2+7-27, mixed mode, sharing)
javac 15.0.2
Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my (late) [answer on the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67949556/why-is-x-not-initialized-in-this/67950376#67950376). The source-code analysis is required by specification.

It's not a case of code reordering in the manner you suggest; that would change behavior, which is forbidden.

Think of the general case: if use of computation was allowed before that computation had been done, then nothing is predictable.

However, in your example here, a sufficiently-smart compiler is allowed to optimize the generated code to (effectively) `System.out.println(-1)`. Neither variable is actually necessary.

If such a thing occurred, it would not affect the required checking for definite assignment.  Logically, simplification happens after validating the source code.

You'd have to examine the generated byte-code to see what actually happened.  Further, in Java the optimization could be done 'later' by just-in-time compilation to native code.